# DS.defaultStore.load(App.foo, payload) only works first time with DS.RESTAdapter

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

***UPDATE:*** 
**THIS IS A NON-ISSUE**
*(see below)*

So I wrote a jsfiddle to show the *bad* behavior except the fiddle works! and my real code doesn't. The only difference is I am using the `RESTAdapter` in my real code so the data is pulled from server instead of `FIXTURES`.

In the jsfiddle: first click *'Simulate 1st manual load'*, then click the *2nd* button to see it work properly (i.e. loading new or updated data to the store multiple times in a row)

http://jsfiddle.net/iceking1624/NZZ42/4/

**The Issue**

I am sending updated information over websockets to my Ember App. I successfully set up a listener to trigger a function on the correct controller and am able to update records the first time. But all successive attempts do not update the store and I wonder if this has to do with the state of the store? But I am unsure of how to handle if that is the case.

This is the code that updates or adds the records that come over websockets:

```
App.SessionController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({

  updateReceived: function(data) {
    console.log(data);      

    DS.defaultStore.load(App.Choice, data.choice);
    DS.defaultStore.load(App.Question, data.question);
  }
});
```

Notice the `console.log(data)` part. Every single time I send updated data via websockets, `updateReceived` is called and the correct data is logged **every time**, but `DS.defaultStore.load(...)` only works the **first** time.

The reason I update both `App.Question` & `App.Choice` is because they have a relationship:

```
App.Question = DS.Model.extend({
  "choices" : DS.hasMany('App.Choice')
});
App.Choice = DS.Model.extend({
  "question" : DS.belongsTo('App.Question')
});
```

I don't think the code below is relevant to the issue but just in case someone is interested, this is how I listen for events over websockets (using socket.io):

```
App.SessionRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  enter: function() {
    this.socket = io.connect('http://10.0.1.4')
  },
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    var self = this;
    this.socket.on('update', function(data) {
      self.controller.send('updateReceived', data)
    })
  }
});
```

Are there any suggestions for how I can continuously load new or updated records directly into the store (and not just once)?

***UPDATE:***

The code is indeed correct. The new data was loading into the store just fine but I wasn't re-rending a `view` correctly when new/updated information was loaded into `DS.defaultStore`

I don't want to delete this question since others may find the information in it useful but vote how you like. I'm sorry I didn't catch this before writing the question.